# Cumbersome navigation of the 10k tools

Tags: bug, status-completed, 10k-tools, navigation, flags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tabs missing for “flags” page in the tools section](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30336/tabs-missing-for-flags-page-in-the-tools-section)

When going to the 10k tools, you are presented with a few tabs with listings. They work as expected, except for the *flags* tab. When I go to the *flag* tab, all the other tabs are not there anymore, so I have to go to *tools* to get them back.

http://img293.imageshack.us/img293/6213/flags1.png
http://img682.imageshack.us/img682/7672/flags2.png

Is this the intended behavior?

Answer (score 0):

A few days ago I was going to post the same question, I even had it typed.

Then I looked at the URL of the different tabs and assumed it was `[by-design]`

**EDIT**:
According to Jeff's answer in the duplicate link, it's indeed `[by-design]`

> ... this page is shared amongst the moderator section as well as the /tools

Comment: oh, and welcome to the 10k world. It's exciting at first, getting gradually boring as you realize you don't have anything else to aim for.

Comment: `[by-design]` is not an excuse for `[bad-design]`

Comment: no, it's not...

Comment: I guess Jeff has never heard of code reuse.